# JavaScript Dropdown Box Issue - Array Map not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, dropdown

I'm new to JavaScript and I am having a massive problem trying to populate a dropdown box with values that are getting queried from a SQL database and returned as a JSON file. My server code seems to work well querying the DB and if I hit the server directly it gives me the following JSON data:

```
[{
    "key": "1AEFF22E-7A2C-4920-B72A-255119E785A8",
    "value": "ExampleSSRSProject"
}, {
    "key": "5A8AE6D3-4A96-4048-9207-6DDDA5B7D19E",
    "value": "MyReportPackage"
}, {
    "key": "EA2CD590-FA01-4094-86EE-414C860E597A",
    "value": "CoverSheet"
}]
```

However, when I run the client page code I just get the error:

> "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop".

Below I have listed my code from the `server.js`, client componentDidMount(), and the render.

```
    app.get('/api/reportList', (req,res) => {    
connection.connect(err=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('content','text/plain');
      res.end(err);
    }
    else{
        var sqlrequest = new sql.Request(connection);
        sqlrequest.query("select ItemId as 'key',Name as 'value' FROM    
         ReportServer$SQL2014.dbo.Catalog where Name <> ''",(err,result)=>{
          if(err){
              console.log(`SQL Error`);
              res.statusCode = 200;
              res.setHeader('content','text/plain');
              res.end("SQL Error");
            }
            else{
              console.log(result);
              res.statusCode = 200;
              res.setHeader('content','text/plain');
              res.json(result.recordset);
              connection.close();
            }
        })

    }
})
});


    componentDidMount() {
fetch("api/reportList")
.then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
  let reportsFromApi = data.map((report,index) => {
    return {key: {index}, display: report}
  });
  this.setState({
    reports: reportsFromApi
  });
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
}); 


      render() {
    return (
      <div>
  <select>
    {this.state.reports.map((report) => <option key={report.ItemId} value={report.Name}     
  >{report.Name}</option>)}
  </select>
      </div>
    )
  }


 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import logo from './logo.svg';
 import './App.css';

 import ReportList from './components/reportList/reportList';

 class App extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
     <div className="App">
       <ReportList/>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: Which framework is this?

Comment: The server is running nodejs

Comment: `trying to populate a dropdown box`.. and what about your front-end, which framework? I ask because I'm a little confused. You say the serverside works fine but then post only the serverside code. I did a little research on your error and it seems to be React? Im asking you for clarification.

Comment: Front end is React

Comment: Can you update your post with your relevant source from your front-end? .. Please keep the backend code in there as well though.

Comment: I'm very new to this so I'm not sure if I'm doing things 100% correctly. When I say server I mean the code in the server.js file. That is where I query the database and return a JSON file. The code I refer to as "client" is calling my api/reportList in the reportList.js file within the client folder and that is where it is failing I believe.

Comment: Well if the error message is a React error, then the front side for that portion of your source will be needed to further track down this bug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is with the data.map function within componentDidMount(). This project is very small and there isn't much more code to post. That's pretty much all of it.

Comment: No to be honest I don't fully understand what I am doing here with the map function...I was grasping at straws trying to fix the error...

Comment: If I hard code an array such as:

var reports = ["Report1", "Report2", "Report3", "Report4"];

It works. It just wont work with my returned JSON data from the database (see above)

Comment: The difference is the return value from your node server (as you show it) is an array of objects, where as the `var reports=` example is an array of strings. I'll upvote you. Hopefully someone verse in React can help you further. The +1 may bring in further attention. ... You should edit your post (if possible) to include the React tag, along side Javascript, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because in your React component, you use the ItemId attribute as the "key" prop.

```
{this.state.reports.map((report) => <option key={report.ItemId} value={report.Name}>...</option>)}
```

The problem is that your "report" objects that are passed from your server code to your client code don't seem to have an "ItemId" property. That means all of your **option** elements are passed a "key" property that is equal to **undefined** and therefore, that is not unique.

You could use the "key" attribute of your "report" objects though, like this:

```
{this.state.reports.map((report) => <option key={report.key} value={report.Name}>...</option>)}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! This worked. In the end all these problems were due to my mis-matched property names!